# What is the name of conversion (parameterized type -> raw type)

Tags: java, jls

According to JLS the conversion like (raw type -> parameterized type) named [Unchecked Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9) .
And what is the name of the reverse conversion (parameterized type -> raw type)?

```
ArrayList<String> arrStr = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList rawArrList = (ArrayList)arrStr;       // what is the conversion name?
```

Comment: Sotirios has a good answer, but depending on quite what you're looking for out of this question, you might also consider the term _erasure_.

Answer (score 3):

That is an identity conversion. The variable is of type `ArrayList`. The value on the right hand side of the assignment is also of type `ArrayList` (because of the cast).  From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.1)

> A conversion from a type to that same type is permitted for any type.

Note that this is not what you described

> And what is the name of the reverse conversion (parameterized type -> raw type)?

A parameterized typed value to its corresponding raw type is a [widening reference conversion.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5)